# Filling array with values but when I check my array with console.log() my array values come up as undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
var myArray = []; //Create an empty array

//Fills empty array with values

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
  myArray[i] = i * i; //Each index is equal to the square of the index number 0=0, 1=1, 2=4, etc.
}

console.log(myArray.length);
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

`console.log(myArray.length);` returns 0 in console

`console.log(myArray[0]);` returns undefined in console

Comment: `myArray.length-1` is `-1`.  Your loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: Omg thank you im so dumb, its because I originally had defined the array with a length and then switched to declaring the array with no length

Comment: When you declared an empty array it's length is zero.  So condition i < myArray.length -1 will always be false  as 0 < -1 . Code inside for loop never runs.

Comment: Check what has been filled `//Fills empty array with values` . Can you check if the filling is correct? There is no declaration for i?  Try `let i=0`

Answer (score 1):

`myArray.length` returns the number of elements in the array `myArray`.

Your array when it reaches the loop has no elements in it (`[]`). So when you do `myArray.length` you will get the number `0` in return.

Thus your for loop will run zero times, as `0 < 0` is never true (and for it to run, your middle condition needs to evaluate to true), meaning when you reach your `console.log` nothing will be set in your array, and so `myArray[0]` will be undefined.

Thus, to generate values you need to use a number greater than zero in your for loop. In the example below, I created an array with `10` elements:

```js
var myArray = []; //Create an empty array

//Fills empty array with values
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // <--- Change to i < 10 here to run 10 times (for i ranging within [0, 10) (0 <= i < 10)
  myArray[i] = i * i; //Each index is equal to the square of the index number 0=0, 1=1, 2=4, etc.
}
console.log(myArray.length); // 10
console.log(myArray[0]); // 0
console.log(myArray[1]); // 1
console.log(myArray[2]); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`myArray.length` when you start the loop is zero. So, It doesn't even go into the loop, hence the array remains as you initialized it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and generate the numbers with the `mapFn` as the second argument:

```js
const generate = n => Array.from({length: n}, (x,i) => i*i)

console.log(generate(5))
console.log(generate(10))
```